# Android - TalkBack accessibility focus on swipe to delete button in Recycleview

Tags: android-recyclerview, uiaccessibility, accessibilityservice, accessibility, accessibility-api

I have drawn the Swipe to delete button(RectF) in Recycle view with the help on

```
 val oBackground = RectF(itemView.right.toFloat() - buttonWidth, itemView.top.toFloat(), itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())
    paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(viewHolder.itemView.context, R.color.color_cc0013)
    canvas.drawRect(optionsBackground, paint)

    // Displays delete drawable within specified bounds
    val deleteBtmp: Bitmap = getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(viewHolder.itemView.context, R.drawable.vector_delete)
    val destination = RectF(
        itemView.right.toFloat() - buttonWidth + paddingLeft,
        itemView.top.toFloat() + paddingTop,
        itemView.right.toFloat() - paddingRight,
        itemView.bottom.toFloat() - paddingBottom
    )
    canvas.drawBitmap(deleteBtmp, null, destination, paint)
```

How I can set TalkBack accessibility focus on swipe to delete button(deleteBtmp) in Recycleview ?

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your delete button is what we call a "virtual view". You'll need to expose it with an AccessibilityNodeProvider.

[ExploreByTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/customview/widget/ExploreByTouchHelper) is a wrapper intended to simplify the process.

*Much* simpler, however, would be to adjust your UI to use a regular button, and take advantage of the built-in accessibility reporting.

Comment: Thanks, @Phil Weaver for showing interest. As per my understanding, ExploreByTouchHelper is working with customer views. But In my case, I have drawn a RecF on the canvas when the user performs swipe left action on any item. Please guide me how I can use ExploreByTouchHelper or AccessibilityNodeProvider in that case. Please share any sample if you have

Comment: Drawing a button on the canvas is pretty much what we mean by a custom view. This feels similar to RadialTimePickerView: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/RadialTimePickerView.java#1070